# Dynamic function definition with macro

Tags: elixir

I have question about following marco. Consider following code snippet:

```
defmodule Assertion do

  defmacro __using__(_options) do
    quote do
      import unquote(__MODULE__)
      Module.register_attribute __MODULE__, :tests, accumulate: true
      @before_compile unquote(__MODULE__)
    end
  end

  defmacro __before_compile__(_env) do
    IO.puts "before compile"
    quote do
      def run, do: Assertion.Test.run(@tests, __MODULE__)     
    end
  end

  defmacro test(description, do: test_block) do
    test_func = String.to_atom(description)
    quote do
      @tests {unquote(test_func), unquote(description)}
      def unquote(test_func)(), do: unquote(test_block)
    end
  end

  defmacro assert({operator, _, [lhs, rhs]}) do
        IO.puts "assert"
    quote bind_quoted: [operator: operator, lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs] do
      Assertion.Test.assert(operator, lhs, rhs)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Assertion.Test do
  def run(tests, module) do                              
    Enum.each tests, fn {test_func, description} ->
      case apply(module, test_func, []) do
        :ok             -> IO.write "."
        {:fail, reason} -> IO.puts """

          ===============================================
          FAILURE: #{description}
          ===============================================
          #{reason}
          """
      end
    end
  end                                                      

  def assert(:==, lhs, rhs) when lhs == rhs do
    :ok
  end
  def assert(:==, lhs, rhs) do
    {:fail, """
      Expected:       #{lhs}
      to be equal to: #{rhs}
      """
    }
  end

  def assert(:>, lhs, rhs) when lhs > rhs do
    :ok
  end
  def assert(:>, lhs, rhs) do
    {:fail, """
      Expected:           #{lhs}
      to be greater than: #{rhs}
      """
    }
  end
end
```

and the following module use the macro:

```
defmodule MathTest do
  use Assertion
  test "integers can be added and subtracted" do
    assert 2 + 3 == 5
    assert 5 - 5 == 10
  end
end
```

Look at the test macro on line

```
def unquote(test_func)(), do: unquote(test_block)
```

I inject here a function to the caller module with the name `integers can be added and subtracted` and before it was converted to an atom.

How it is possible to give a name to a function with space? And what is the `()` after `def unquote(test_func)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `quote` and `unquote` do is create an abstract syntax tree(AST). Lets take a look and compare

normal function definition

```
iex(1)> quote do def foo(), do: :ok end
{:def, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
 [{:foo, [context: Elixir], []}, [do: :ok]]}
```

We can see the name of the function is stored in the AST as `{:foo, [context: Elixir], []}`, that is, the name is stored as an atom

function definition using `unquote`

```
iex(2)> foovar=:'foo var'              
:"foo var"
iex(3)> quote do def unquote(foovar)(), do: :ok end
{:def, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
 [{:"foo var", [context: Elixir], []}, [do: :ok]]}
```

here the name is stored in the AST with the name part of the tuple as the previously defined variable, `:"foo var"`

You could call these sort of functions using the built-in function [`apply`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3)

---

the `()` is optional. Some people, myself included, prefer to use them in all function definitions and function calls for consistency’s sake.

---

Note:

One of the things I like better about the Erlang syntax is that function names and atoms look the same, and they sort of are the same. That is you can say `Module.foo` is just sugar for `apply(Module, :foo, [])`. In elixir function names look like variables, which combined with optional parenthesise can make the code more difficult to read and understand quickly.